# Using Cron job for php-fpm restart

Tags: cron, centos

I used this command in ssh as root user and works well

```
/usr/bin/systemctl reload php-fpm
```

But in cron job it won't work

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information than that. 
Which crontab are you adding this to (i.e. what command are you using to modify the crontab?

What is in your crontab?

Is cron running?

Have you checked the user's local mail? Cron emails output from cron jobs.